# How many kinds of tables are there in DolphinDB?

Tags: database, time-series, dolphindb

I have read the doc and try it myself almost whole night, sting confusing about this question.

I'm specifically interested in understanding the relationship between the `DFS table` and the `dimension table`. According to the documentation within [Data Form](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/DataTypesandStructures/DataForms/Table.html), it is suggested that the `dimension table` is **a variant** of the `DFS table`. However, in the documentation relating to the ['create' statement](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/SQLStatements/create.html), it appears that the `dimension table` is distinct from the `DFS table`.

Furthermore, the documentation concerning the data forms of tables states that there are only two types: In-Memory and DFS. However, there exists a third kind of table that doesn't fall into either of the aforementioned categories — a table saved on the local file system.

Hope anyone knows DolphindDB could help, really thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to share my attempt at answering the question I recently posed. Please note that my understanding may not align perfectly with the official documentation, and I welcome corrections from anyone with familiarity with DolphinDB.

From what I gather, DolphinDB databases can be classified into three categories: In-Memory, Local File System, and Distributed File System (DFS). In the latter two categories, there's the option to designate partition types and schemas for partitioned tables.

Consequently, the tables could fall under at least five types: In-Memory tables, partitioned tables in file systems (both local and DFS), and tables in file systems (again, both local and DFS).

What puzzles me is the lack of emphasis on the Local File System database in the official documentation, despite its frequent appearance in example codes.

I hope this interpretation brings some clarity to who read it.